# How much did Netflix contribute, as part of the production committee, for Devilman Crybaby?

Tags: anime-production, devilman-crybaby

I watched the first few episodes of Devilman Crybaby on Netflix and the animation was really awesome. I know the series was directed by Masaaki Yuasa, a really good animator and director.

However, I think we can all admit the quality of this show is above average. Netflix was part of the production committee and they certainly made a big contribution to the budget to the studio Science Saru.

I'd like to have sourced data on the total budget of the series and the amount Netflix has given.

Comment: This data is usually private and not released to the public, for a variety of reasons, unless leaked or the publishers/committees themselves for reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting as it may seem, we likely will never know the specifics, due to the reasons [кяαzєя♦'s](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/%d0%ba%d1%8f%ce%b1z%d1%94%d1%8f) comment already pointed out.

Non the less, I figured, why not try and ask Netflix themselves?
[image]
[image]

All though it is not much information, we did however pin down the fact that Netflix only pays for *exclusive rights* and nothing else.
As the support also suggests, it is somewhat of a trade secret.

I haven't personally tried to mail them as support suggested. However I don't think it is likely that a more descriptive/precise price would be mentioned by the pr team.